# Image overlay: Height > 100%. Is not scrolling in Safari but in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: css, reactjs, safari, overlay

I am trying to implement an overlay with a fullscreen images below each other. It needs to scroll. But scrolling does not work in Safari. It works in Chrome/Firefox. I have only tested the newest versions.

Have tried to make the demo simpler, removing ImageSrcset but it does not help.

**Codesandbox (please open the browser in new window/tab to see problem):**
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/secretlifeof/react-overlay-images/tree/master/?fontsize=14

**Github repo:**
https://github.com/secretlifeof/react-overlay-images

Do I need to implement scroll lock so that the underlay does not try to scroll? I have tried to look at how others have implemented overlays, but I cannot understand how this implementation is different.

**Versions:**
Safari: v12.1.2